# RegEx review for ^([2-8])(\.[0-9]{1,3})?|(^[9])(\.[0-9]{1,1})?$

Tags: regex

```
^([2-8])(\.[0-9]{1,3})?|(^[9])(\.[0-9]{1,1})?$
```

The requirement is to validate:

- Numbers between 2 to 9.9 inlcusive
- All numbers in this range can have up to 3 decimal places EXCEPT 9.9
- 9.899, 9.900 is acceptable BUT 9.910 is NOT

The regex I have specified does not work properly for all numbers in range 9.XXX
I need help to fix this regex for 9.XXX

Comment: It would help if you mentioned which flavour of Regex you use (perl5, posix, .NET etc.)?

Comment: @sehe I am using .NET flavor. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^([2-8])(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$|^(9)(\.[0-8][0-9]{0,2}|\.90{0,2})?$
```

if you want to catch 9.900 and the others

Try here http://regexr.com?2un13 with some examples.

Answer (score 2):

`^([2-8](\.\d{1,3})?|9(\.[0-8]\d{0,2})?|9\.90{0,2})$`